# Using Google Code-Prettify with Typescript and Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, google-code-prettify

I'm pretty new to using Typescript and Angular 4, and I am having trouble integrating Google Code-Prettify with the angular CLI setup.

I am trying to figure out how to import code-prettify to use dynamically with my components, but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

I've tried installing with NPM and importing PR from the package, but PR comes in as an empty object.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can change some code in prettify.js:



//old code in here
if (typeof define === "function" && define['amd']) {
    define("google-code-prettify", [], function () {
     return PR;
     });
}
//new code in here
      
if(typeof module==="object"&&typeof module.exports==="object") {
    module.exports = PR;
} else if (typeof define === "function" && define['amd']) {
    define("google-code-prettify", [], function () {
     return PR;
    });
}




use case like this:



let prettify = require('../../dep/prettify');
$("#doc-view").html(virtualDom);
prettify.prettyPrint();
```

Comment: I haven't got a chance to try this yet, but looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thanks!